# Can I gulp-notify when a watched task completes?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-notify

We have a gulpfile with ~12 tasks, 4 of which are activated by a `gulp.watch`.  I would like to use `gulp-notify` when a task started by `gulp.watch` completes.  I don't want `gulp-notify` to do anything if a task is run directly.  Sample code below:

```
const
    debug = require("gulp-debug"),
    gulp = require("gulp"),
    notify = require("gulp-notify");

gulp.task("scripts:app", function () {
    return gulp.src(...)
        .pipe(debug({ title: "tsc" }))
        .pipe(...);                // <--- if i add notify here, 
                                   //      I will always get a notification
});

gulp.task("watch", function () {
    gulp.watch("ts/**/*.ts", ["scripts:app"]);
});
```

If I pipe to `notify` inside the `'scripts:app'` task, it will make a notification every time that task runs, regardless of how that task was started.  Again, I want to notify when the *watched task* completes.

I considered adding a task `'scripts:app:notify'` that depends on `'scripts:app'`, but if possible I'd like to avoid creating "unnecessary" tasks.

I also tried the following:

```
gulp.watch("ts/**/*.ts", ["scripts:app"])
    .on("change", function (x) { notify('changed!').write(''); });
```

But that results in a notification for every file changed.  I want a notification when the task *completes*.

In other words, if I run `gulp scripts:app`, I *should not* get a notification.  When I run `gulp watch` and change a watched file, I *should* get a notification.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could give a param to the `scripts:app` task and check with `if`/`else` if the notification should be dropped or not.

Comment: @Sandrooco how would i pass in that parameter from the watch?  The task is identified by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding params to your build script:

```
function buildApp(notify){
    return gulp.src(...)
        .pipe(...)
        .pipe(function(){
            if (notify) {
                //drop notification
            }
        });
    });      
}

//Register watcher
gulp.watch("ts/**/*.ts", function(){
    var notify = true;
    buildApp(notify);
});

//Register task so we can still call it manually
gulp.task("scripts:app", buildApp.bind(null, false));
```

As you can see, `buildApp` is a simple function. It's callable through a watcher or a "normal" task registration.